# How to check the default path for Powershell modules?

Tags: powershell

I want to check the default path for Powershell modules. Is there any command to do this?

Please help me through this.

Thank you.

Comment: Quick google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=I+want+to+check+the+default+path+for+Powershell+modules&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a command to check the dafault path for Powershell modules.

Use below command :

> Get-content env:PSModulePath

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in :  `$env:PSModulePath`

It's not in a powershell var, but in the process environment.